# PyQGIS in PyCharm: Is there a way to access a running QGIS App from PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, qgis, pyqgis

I have to do some scripting with pyqgis and would like to do this in PyCharm. However, I need to be able to have access to the running QGIS App from Pycharm, as I need to be able to access active layers (which doesn't work in PyCharm yet, only from the in-built editor).
For example the following code does work when executing from the Python console inside QGIS but not when you execute it from Pycharm:

`layer = iface.active()`

Is there a way to NOT use the in-built editor, but instead using PyCharm and still be able to access the running QGIS App? The in-built editor must have a connection to the running App.

Is it possible to configure QGIS to use an external IDE/Script Editor?

Comment: Did you found a way in the meantime? I think its just working when QGIS is started right from the Pycharm itself ... there are several tutorials starting Pycharm using a .bat file which contains the whole config ...

Comment: Maybe this one might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76108809/how-to-run-qgis-python-editor-through-pycharm-in-ubuntu-os